# Firestore setting error: "The timestampsInSnapshots setting now defaults to true"

Tags: javascript, angular, google-cloud-firestore

I'm doing CRUD in angular through firestore, and after inserting first data in database, from the second one this error is coming up whenever i refresh my page . I have imported the apk files in environment.ts, but i dont know about this error , how to fix it .

[image: this is the error on my console]

Answer (score 0):

app.component.ts:

```
constructor (
    private db: AngularFirestore
) {
    db.firestore.settings({ timestampsInSnapshots: true });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in your code you're calling the equivalent of:

```
db.firestore.settings({ timestampsInSnapshots: true })
```

This used to be required to configure how Firestore behaved when you have date fields. The warning says that this is no longer needed, so you can remove the above code from your app.